# PHP form using post method, submit by url

Tags: php, forms, url, post, form-submit

I need some confirmation if this is possible or not please , it seems a simple thing compared to the related topics I've read on this... I'll outline my problem as clear as I can.

I have a RPI, it serves a nginx and php website to control my lights. I have built this website myself and Im choosing the post method as I don't need to get any information from the server. I just want to send commands. It's just a simple form with buttons each giving a different shell command. I suppose technically it does return the output but I don't need it for my purpose.

On the same wifi I can simply send a ssh command (same as the form does) using tasker. However I don't want ssh open to the Web.  That's what the website was for. however it would be fantastic if tasker could send the commands via the website for better automation.

What I'm looking for is something like the below url that I can have tasker simple open in the browser and the command run.

Mywebsite.freedns.ns1.com/lights.php?=$_POST['bedlight1']

I simply want the url to be coded into tasker for it to open in the browser on my phone. I don't want to pass any data other than the php post. I just would like an example of the syntax if it is even possible... thanks sorry if this has been answered and I couldn't find it... thanks in advance, matt

Comment: You can't encode POST data in the URL like this, for that you need to [use the HTTP GET method](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp), which will populate the PHP superglobal array `$_GET` (as opposed to `$_POST`). Your URL would look something like `example.com/lights.php?bedlight=on` and then you check in PHP with `if(!empty($_GET['bedlight'])){ exec('/path/to/command'); }`

Comment: Ok thanks for the clear answer but i dont wish to use the GET method. This got me thinking tho, could I use several php pages to handle this by passing the post through a script? 
So if I call the url ......com/bedlight1.php

It could contain something like the following:

<?php

include_once('lights.php');
echo $_POST['bedlight1'];

?php>

Would sort of thing work? Or is ajax the only way to go? I'd rather have 10 or so files than switch to get...

Comment: Why are you even trying to pass these commands through a query string at all if you don't want to use GET?  Seems like you're trying to put a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: The page.php? Is the only example of syntax I have. I have solved this via not doing it all. Within tasker there is an option to do a "http post" where I can set server:port with a path to the file (php) and can submit data... This works better...